# Tags for questions asking for published examples?

Tags: discussion, tags

So far on writers.SE we've had a few questions asking for examples of published works that show how to do something well.  For example

- [Examples for books that don't use (traditional) chapters](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/976/examples-for-books-that-dont-use-traditional-chapters)
- [Story for children without a happy ending](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/287/story-for-children-without-a-happy-ending)
- [What books should I read before writing a non-humanoid point of view story?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/499/what-books-should-i-read-before-writing-a-non-humanoid-point-of-view-story)

Should we create a tag that unifies these questions?  I believe that they do provide value to the site, although unless they ask for "...and why do your examples work" or other additional detail they *certainly* fall into the category of lists of X and therefore are prime candidates for CW if we choose to allow it.

If you do think we should have a single tag that covers such questions, what would it be?  `published-examples`?

Answer (score 2):

I think they fall all into the category of lists of books and therefore I suggest to tag them with `book-list`, CW or not.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a meta-tag, and I see no reason to create such a tag.

Comment: Agreed.  We want questions about, say, writing good dialogue to be grouped together whether they involve advice or examples, and I'm having trouble seeing value in further grouping the subset that happen to be examples.